# MySql Connector/NET doesn't support geometry other than points?

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I've been trying to map polygon geometry from MySQL into .NET using MySQL connector, but it only maps to point. I wonder if it supports the mapping of geometries other than point.

Comment: You don't specify which versions of anything that you use, but the documentation here might help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework50.html

Comment: The version of MySQL connector that I am using is 6.9.9.0, which I believe is the latest version. I did try with polygon, but it just maps to point.

Comment: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/70 (seems point is only implemented Geometry type)